# Reduce/Resolve without roots/radicals

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, resolve

Is there a way to convince Mathematica to perform quantifier elimination on a semialgebraic set and yield a resulting semialgebraic set whose representation does not involve any roots or radicals, i.e., is given as a Boolean combination of polynomial inequalities? Here is a simple example:

```
org = Reduce[Exists[{z}, x^2 + 2 x y <= z^3 && x y + z <= 5], {x, y}, Reals]
```

yields

```
(x < 0 && y >= Root[-125 + x^2 + 77 x #1 - 15 x^2 #1^2 + x^3 #1^3 &, 1]) || x == 0 ||
(x > 0 && y <= Root[-125 + x^2 + 77 x #1 - 15 x^2 #1^2 + x^3 #1^3 &, 1])
```

**Update:**
In this specific example, we can use `ToRadicals` and manually introduce two variables `w1`, `w2` for which the following holds:

```
cond = w1^3 == Sqrt[3] w2 - 90 x^6 - 9 x^8 && 
       w2^2 == 2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16 &&
       w2 >= 0
```

Substituting these variables for the respective radical expressions yields the following Boolean combination of polynomial inequalities:

```
new =
((x < 0 && ((6 w1 x^3 y >=
   2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) w1^2 + 30 w1 x^2 - 4 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^4 && 
     6 w1 x^3 > 0) || (6 w1 x^3 y <= 
      2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) w1^2 + 30 w1 x^2 - 4 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^4 && 
     6 w1 x^3 < 0))) || 
x == 0 || 
(x > 0 && ((6 w1 x^3 y <= 
      2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) w1^2 + 30 w1 x^2 - 4 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^4 && 
     6 w1 x^3 > 0) || (6 w1 x^3 y >= 
      2^(2/3) 3^(1/3) w1^2 + 30 w1 x^2 - 4 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^4 && 
     6 w1 x^3 < 0)))) &&
w1^3 == Sqrt[3] w2 - 90 x^6 - 9 x^8 && 
w2^2 == 2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16 &&
w2 >= 0
```

`Reduce`/`Resolve` are able to prove the equivalence:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x, y, w1, w2}, Implies[cond, Equivalent[org, new]]], {}, Reals]
True

Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, Exists[{w1, w2}, Equivalent[org, new]]], Reals]
True
```

However, I wonder about a general solution which should in principle exist.

Comment: What different form might one obtain?

Comment: A Boolean combination of polynomial inequalities p(x) >= 0 (x being a vector here).

Comment: I meant for this specific example. When everything is an equation this is standard variable elimination. But for inequalities it is not clear to me what the result above might be.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I extended my post accordingly. However, the approach is not insightful for the general case.

Comment: @MathGaudium: Could you indicate the edited places in your question? Such behavior is standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such away:

```
ToRadicals[Root[-125 + x^2 + 77 x #1 - 15 x^2 #1^2 + x^3 #1^3 &, 1], Assumptions -> x < 0]
```

> `5/x - (2 (2/3)^( 1/3) x)/(-90 x^6 - 9 x^8 +  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16])^( 1/3) + (-90 x^6 - 9 x^8 +  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16])^(1/3)/( 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^3)`

```
ToRadicals[Root[-125 + x^2 + 77 x #1 - 15 x^2 #1^2 + x^3 #1^3 &, 1], Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

> `5/x - (2 (2/3)^( 1/3) x)/(-90 x^6 - 9 x^8 +  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16])^( 1/3) + (-90 x^6 - 9 x^8 +  Sqrt[3] Sqrt[2732 x^12 + 540 x^14 + 27 x^16])^(1/3)/( 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) x^3)`

Comment: Thank you. I also extended my post with a manually constructed solution that involves two additional variables. However, I wonder how this can be done in general with Mathematica without relying on `ToRadicals` which cannot be used for in general. It should be possible though because a semialgebraic set can always be represented as a Boolean combination of polynomial inequalities.